# flake8 max-complexity per file

Tags: python, django, flake8

I have a legacy project using flake8 to check code quality and complexity, but the project has some very complicated (terrible) services which are returning complexity WARNING messages:

```
./service1.py:127:1: C901 'some_method' is too complex (50)
```

We are slowly transitioning into making them better, but we need to make jenkins (which is running tests and flake8) pass.

Is there a way to specify ignoring a code error or complexity per file, or even per method?

Comment: Something similar was proposed but wasn't accepted: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/89#taking-the-proposal-further. The [second accepted option](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/merge_requests/57) can be used in your case, i.e. add `# noqa: ignore=C901` in front of the `def` line.

Comment: Those links are dead now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`flake8-per-file-ignores`](https://github.com/snoack/flake8-per-file-ignores):

```
pip install flake8-per-file-ignores
```

And then in your config file:

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    your/legacy/path/*.py: C901,E402
```

If you want a per-method/function solution you can use the in-source `# noqa: ignore=C901` syntax.

Comment: As of Flake8 3.7.0, `--per-file-ignores` is supported out of the box w/o installing any plugins. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56187807/244297) for details.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Flake8 3.7.0+, you can use the [`--per-file-ignores`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=per-file-ignores#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores) option to ignore the warning for a specific file:

```
flake8 --per-file-ignores='service1.py:C901'
```

This can also be specified in a [config file](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html):

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    service1.py: C901
```

Answer (score -2):

In your flake config add:

```
[flake8]
ignore = C901
max-complexity = <some_number>
```

Try to experiment with the value for `max-complexity` to get more relevant number for your project.

**Edit:**
You can also ignore a [line of your code](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/stable/user/violations.html#in-line-ignoring-errors) or a [file](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html#ignoring-entire-files).

**After you are done with the refactoring don't forget to change these settings.**

Comment: yeah of course I know I can disable C901, but I don't want to disable it for ALL files.

Comment: Ok, then maybe this will be useful http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html#