# How to decompose subroutines in object orientated approach to solve "Flake8 Function is too complex (C901)"?

Tags: python, oop, flake8

I am writing a function `build_hierarchy_config` within a class 'P', that calls recursively `recursive_build_hierarchy_config` .
This function called on instance P1 iterates over complex dict structure ('config' attribute) and compares all items with same 'config' attribute from another 'P' instance (called P2), that is parent to P1.
The the comparison logic is split into few functions:

- recursive call is `recursive_build_hierarchy_config`
- comparison of dicts (iterating over complex structure) is in
  `get_more_strict_config`
- comparing single item is in `cmp_config_item`

So the code looks like below:

```
import decimal
from typing import Optional
from attrdict import AttrDict

class Config(AttrDict):
    """Represent P config."""

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        super(Config, self).__init__(some_dict)


class P(dict):
    """Represents P object."""

    def build_hierarchy_config(self,
                               hierarchy_config_type: str):
        """Fill the hierarchy_config or parent_hierarchy_config attribute."""

        def cmp_config_item(slave: Optional[decimal.Decimal],
                            master: Optional[decimal.Decimal],
                            cmp_func: str) -> Optional[decimal.Decimal]:
            """Compare two numbers with custom 'None' handling."""

            if cmp_func not in ['min', 'max']:
                raise Exception(
                    f'comparison function {cmp_func} not supported')
            if slave is not None and master is not None:
                return eval(cmp_func + '(' + str(slave) + ',' +
                            str(master) + ')')
            elif slave is None and master is None:
                return None
            elif slave is None:
                return master
            elif master is None:
                return slave

        def get_more_strict_config(config, parent_config) -> Config:
            """Combine configs and return most strict combinaton of values."""

            # some logic with few for and if/else
            return config

        def recursive_build_hierarchy_config(pieceId: Optional[str]):
            if pieceId is None:
                return None
            else:
                p = P()
                parent_config = recursive_build_hierarchy_config(
                    p.parentPieceId)

                return get_more_strict_config(p.config, parent_config)

        if hierarchy_config_type == 'hierarchy_config':
            self.hierarchyConfig = recursive_build_hierarchy_config(
                self.id)
        elif hierarchy_config_type == 'parent_hierarchy_config':
            self.parenthierarchyConfig = recursive_build_hierarchy_config(
                self.parentPieceId)
```

but then running `flake8` gives me the error:

`C901 'P.build_hierarchy_config' is too complex (12)`

Which means that complexity for `build_hierarchy_config` sums complexity for all sub-functions.

**Option 1**
I can easily fix it by moving function `cmp_config_item` out of `build_hierarchy_config` namespace (not sure if this is proper wording) and locating in the main scope:

```
import decimal
from typing import Optional

from attrdict import AttrDict


class Config(AttrDict):
    """Represent P config."""

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        super(Config, self).__init__(some_dict)


class P(dict):
    """Represents P object."""

    def build_hierarchy_config(self,
                               hierarchy_config_type: str):
        """Fill the hierarchy_config or parent_hierarchy_config attribute."""

        def get_more_strict_config(config, parent_config) -> Config:
            """Combine configs and return most strict combinaton of values."""

            # some logic with few for and if/else
            return config

        def recursive_build_hierarchy_config(pieceId: Optional[str]):
            if pieceId is None:
                return None
            else:
                p = P()
                parent_config = recursive_build_hierarchy_config(
                    p.parentPieceId)

                return get_more_strict_config(p.config, parent_config)

        if hierarchy_config_type == 'hierarchy_config':
            self.hierarchyConfig = recursive_build_hierarchy_config(
                self.id)
        elif hierarchy_config_type == 'parent_hierarchy_config':
            self.parenthierarchyConfig = recursive_build_hierarchy_config(
                self.parentPieceId)


def cmp_config_item(slave: Optional[decimal.Decimal],
                    master: Optional[decimal.Decimal],
                    cmp_func: str) -> Optional[decimal.Decimal]:
    """Compare two numbers with custom 'None' handling."""

    if cmp_func not in ['min', 'max']:
        raise Exception(
            f'comparison function {cmp_func} not supported')
    if slave is not None and master is not None:
        return eval(cmp_func + '(' + str(slave) + ',' +
                    str(master) + ')')
    elif slave is None and master is None:
        return None
    elif slave is None:
        return master
    elif master is None:
        return slave
```

Now flake8 does not complain anymore. But this makes function `cmp_config_item` available for the whole scope of the module, and makes code less structured (there is no indication that this function is designated to use in selected scope.

**Option 2**
I can silence this message for function by adding `# noqa: ignore=C901` after `def build_hierarchy_config` as described [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704775/flake8-max-complexity-per-file#49634641).
But this suppress checking the function `build_hierarchy_config` itself, so will not be accepted.

Both solutions are trade offs. 
I am not an OOP expert, so the question is:
Is there any proper/better way to organise those subroutines that would be
in line with object orientated programming rules